# What is Quotas in Amazon web service context

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, quota

what is AWS Service Utilization Quota (Limits) ? Based on the definition provided in docs it says " AWS implements quotas to provide highly available and reliable service to all customers, and protect you from unintentional spend. Each quota starts with an AWS default value. " .

Basically my question here is what are resources in that definition ?  Are they computers , nodes , cluster or some sort of distributed computation nodes or it is something else ?

Secondly , if they are different nodes or computation resources, they should be distributed, right ?

I really appreciate if someone can simplify this def for me ?

For instance what happens in a Sage Maker service with quota of 20 , does it mean in the training batches can be distributed over 20 nodes for fwd and back prop training ?

Comment: General definition of resource is as [follows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html): "In AWS, a resource is an **entity that you can work with**. Examples include an Amazon EC2 instance, an AWS CloudFormation stack, or an Amazon S3 bucket. "

Answer (score 2):

Every service has different quotas that relate to how that service works.

For example, Amazon EC2 has a maximum number of concurrently-running instances, number of security groups, number of rules in a security group, etc. The limits are listed in documentation, and also under **Service Quotas** in the AWS management console.

Amazon SageMaker limits can be found here: [Amazon SageMaker endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html)